# Abstract class method with different return type in derived class

Tags: c#, abstract, return-type, base-class

I have this abstract class:

```
 abstract class Animal {

    public abstract List<??????> getAnimals();

 }
```

I want to change the return type to make this:

```
     Animal animal;

     if(/*Somthing*/){
          animal = new Cat();
          catList = animal.getAnimals();
     }else{
          animal = new Dog(); 
          dogList = animal.getAnimals();
     }
```

I want to return `CatModelList` and a `DogModelList`.

Is this possible if dog and cat would have `Animal`s as base? And if not what I think is the answer, what would be the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Then you need generics to supply the type:

```
abstract class Animal<T> : Animal where T : Animal
{
    public abstract List<T> GetAnimals();
}

abstract class Animal
// base type to make things easier. Put in all the non-generic properties.
{ }
```

Where `T` could be `Dog`, `Cat` or any other type deriving from `Animal`:

```
class Dog : Animal<Dog>
{ }
```

Then you can use it using the derived class:

```
Dog d = new Dog();
animal = d;
dogList = d.GetAnimals();
```

It seems weird though. In an instance of `Animal` you get the animals? I don't get that logic.

Comment: It has no logic i just want to keep it easy. because actually i need to load diffrent models from tables with an adapter pattern. and its a part of study.
Thank you for your awnser!

Comment: Do I have to instanciate the Animal for each Generic Type or can i instanciate it only at beginning like in my Question?